# Change icon shape and display [Android 11 Go edition]

Tags: home-screen, app-icons

Just bought a new Nokia C01 which runs Android 11 Go Edition. `Settings > About phone > Android version` has these details:

- Android version = 11
- Kernel version = 4.14.193+
- Build number = 00WW_1_210

On the main run screen, the icon for a group of apps shows up to four icons from the apps internal to the group. The `Chess` group below is a good example...very messy!

[image: Messy icons in Android 11]

The icon for a single app, like `Iron Will`, is perfect. On my previous phone, the group icon was taken from the 1st app in the group. This was a much cleaner design.

Is it possible to configure the group icon display on the home screen on my version of Android?

When I click-hold > Home settings on my version of Android, there are no options to modify the style or arrangement of icons on the home screen.

Comment: You can use a 3rd party launcher app, e.g. Nova Launcher allows to configure the icon shape, background and so on of app groups (at least on regular Android, not sure about Android Go).

Comment: The customization depends on the Home Screen/Launcher app. This behavior looks the same on [Pixel Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher) (default launcher of Nexus and Pixel devices).